# SQL Pivot count incomplete and complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

First of let me start by saying that my SQL know how is pretty limited.
So I have below table
[image: table]

Now I would like to create a pivot in SQL that looks like so
[image: pivot]

Now PN from second column can repeat from time to time.
While I managed to count complete and incomplete, can't seem to figure out how to say PN and EntryDate combo (concatenation) is unique and want to count based on that (see green and yellow rows as same PN).
Basically if "Completed" row has data is complete and if null is incomplete.

Database is MS SQL
All help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this below logic using Aggregation-

```
SELECT PN,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Incomplete,
COUNT(*) Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY PN
```

OR

```
SELECT PN,
COUNT(completed) Completed,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(completed) Incomplete,
COUNT(*) Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY PN
```

As you commented and wants separate records by EntryDate as well, you can do this folowing-

```
SELECT PN,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
SUM(CASE WHEN completed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Incomplete,
COUNT(*) Total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY PN, EntryDate
```

Comment: this works only if you don't consider entry date
I would want to show based on entry date  
see my example (green and yellow rows contain same PN, but different entry date)

Comment: Just apply an additional GROUP BY on entrydate column like - GROUP BY PIN, EntryDate.

Comment: I did this, but results are not right


`    SELECT PN, Convert(VARCHAR(10),EntryDate,101) AS Data, SUM(CASE WHEN Completed IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed, SUM(CASE WHEN Completed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Incomplete, COUNT(*) Total FROM CST_MAIN GROUP BY PN, Data   `

Comment: Use ----- GROUP BY PN, Convert(VARCHAR(10),EntryDate,101)